# Create an image file from a pixel array in React Native

Tags: react-native, image

I am asking how I should go about creating an image from a array of pixels in react native. I have done some searching on npm and github but everything I find seems to be something different that what I'm looking for.

It would be appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction.